# WINAPI - WM_COMMAND vs. WM_MENUCOMMAND for fixed menu and dynamic submenu

Tags: c, winapi, menu, notifications

Trying to create a tray application in C using WINAPI in VS2019. There is a fixed menu and a dynamic submenu, for which the number of items is unknown in advance. Main menu is coming from RC file and submenu is generated dynamically (example below).

I managed to either use MENUINFO and trigger WM_MENUCOMMAND for all items of both menus, or not to use it and rely on WM_COMMAND only.

**Question:** Is it possible to trigger and process WM_COMMAND from the main menu, and at the same time WM_MENUCOMMAND from the submenu to get the id of the dynamic submenu selected item? Else what is the correct way to identify items added dynamically?

*Menus creation code:*

```
hMenu = LoadMenu(g_hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CONTEXTMENU));

if (hMenu)
{
    hSubMenu = GetSubMenu(hMenu, 0);

    if (hSubMenu)
    {
        // our window must be foreground before calling TrackPopupMenu
        // or the menu will not disappear when the user clicks away
        SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);

        hSubMenu2 = CreatePopupMenu();

        wchar_t warr[29];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            swprintf(warr, sizeof warr / sizeof * warr, L"Item: %i", i);
            AppendMenu(hSubMenu2, MF_STRING, i + 1000, warr);
        }

        AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hSubMenu2, L"Sub-Sub Menu");

        MENUINFO mi;
        memset(&mi, 0, sizeof(mi));
        mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
        mi.fMask = MIM_STYLE;
        mi.dwStyle = MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS;
        SetMenuInfo(hSubMenu2, &mi);

        // respect menu drop alignment
        UINT uFlags = TPM_RIGHTBUTTON;
        if (GetSystemMetrics(SM_MENUDROPALIGNMENT) != 0)
            uFlags |= TPM_RIGHTALIGN;
        else 
            uFlags |= TPM_LEFTALIGN;

        TrackPopupMenuEx(hSubMenu, uFlags, pt.x, pt.y, hwnd, NULL);
    }

    DestroyMenu(hMenu);
}
```

*Message processing code:*

```
case WM_MENUCOMMAND:;
    HMENU menu = (HMENU)lParam;
    int idx = wParam;
    wchar_t buffer[10];
    swprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer / sizeof * buffer, L"%i", idx);

    if (menu == hSubMenu2)
    {
        MessageBox(hwnd, buffer, L"Test", MB_OK);
    }
    else
        break;

case WM_COMMAND: // incomplete; for information
{
    int const wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
    // Parse the menu selections:
    switch (wmId)
    {
    case IDM_LOWINK:
        ShowLowInkBalloon();
        break;

    case IDM_NOINK:
        ShowNoInkBalloon();
        break;

// ...
```

Comment: Not clear what you ask. If your target is to trigger an action upon a menu/submenu selection `WM_COMMAND` is enough to identify the action to actuate. If you need also to access to the menu/submenu structure to apply some modifications, i.e. add remove entries or change a label, the `WM_MENUCOMMAND` is the right choice that supply you data to access menu structures for update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to trigger and process WM_COMMAND from the main menu, and at the same time WM_MENUCOMMAND from the submenu to get the id of the dynamic submenu selected item?

From the documentation: The WM_MENUCOMMAND message is sent only for menus that are defined with the MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS flag set in the dwStyle member of the MENUINFO structure.

And: MNS_NOTIFYBYPOS is a menu header style and has no effect when applied to individual sub menus.

As I understand this, you can set this flag for your menu and clicking an item will then sent the index in the WM_MENUCOMMAND message. Now you either remember the index to know which item has been clicked, or you could have stored additional information with the item when you created it, retrieve it, and use it. For example, you can now translate this index to a WM_COMMAND message.

Unfortunately I could not find more information about what is a "menu header style". You will need to experiment.

---

**EDIT**

I have a generic module that manages dynamic menus. It is too much to copy it here (over 400 lines), but I'll give you the outline.

When creating the menu item, I set the `wID` member of the `MENUITEMINFO` struct to a negative value, which now will be distinctive from all other menu IDs. Upon click it is passed to my own handler. Now *I assume* this can be a `WM_COMMAND` menu ID and will be handled in the `WM_COMMAND` handler (I had other needs).

The basic creation code is (assumes the sub menu exists already, so only adding items):

```
MENUITEMINFO MenuItemInfo = {sizeof(MENUITEMINFO), (MIIM_STATE|MIIM_TYPE|MIIM_ID|MIIM_DATA),
                            MFT_STRING, MFS_ENABLED, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    // pMenuItem is my menu struct. replace with your data as needed
    MenuItemInfo.wID= IDM_MY_CMD; // the menu identifier; assumed here a WM_COMMAND id
    MenuItemInfo.fState= (pMenuItem->bEnabled?MFS_ENABLED:MFS_DISABLED);
    MenuItemInfo.cch= strlen(pMenuItem->szName);
    MenuItemInfo.dwTypeData= pMenuItem->szName;
    MenuItemInfo.dwItemData= (unsigned long)pMenuItem->pUser; // any data the user wants to store

    InsertMenuItem (hMenu, position, TRUE, &MenuItemInfo);
```

Comment: I missed the "...has no effect when applied to individual sub menus" part in the doc. So bottom line, not possible. Question remains about how to identify dynamically added items in WM_COMMAND handler.